# Share Ubuntu between two computers and explore ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, telnet

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 using the full hard disk in my laptop and a WUBI Ubuntu 12.04 using 30 GB in my desktop. Now I want to explore the networking features of Ubuntu. Like telnet and ssh. CLI etc etc to become a programmer.As I am a beginner I have no idea where should I start specially for using the feature so that I can control my desktop through my laptop.Or else, how can I setup one as server and other as a user. To be straightforward I am reading the book a practical guide to Ubuntu by sobell and many feature of that book requires at least two pc's with networking support that is remote computer.I have a cat 4 Ethernet cable but don’t know what to do.So if anyone can point out from  where to start and give the useful links it would be very helpful. thanks!

Comment: It this useful ? [Connecting to ubuntu server via ssh externally](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181723/connecting-to-ubuntu-server-via-ssh-externally)

Answer (score 1):

you can test them on a single computer also by install client and server software on same system but if you want to do it with two system connect them (I assume you know networking)

install server and client softwares example

Telnet: install telnetd (`sudo apt-get install telnetd`) in one computer and access it via access terminal as `telnet <ip of second system>`

SSH : install `openssh`

FTP : `vsftpd`

HTTP: `apache2`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and best option --one I use quite extensively when testing new distros or doing security work, is using Virtualbox.  While you could install a variety of packages on your primary desktop (Apache, Vsftp, etc) to experiment, it is much safer and easier to do it in a virtual environment where you can start, stop, and roll back changes when you screw something up.

There are several tutorials available [elsewhere](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox) that explain how to install Ubutnu (or any other OS) inside Virtualbox.  Good luck!

```
apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: I dont want to use virtualbox as I have some bitter experience with it. BTW, Actually I tried connecting my two PC's with the cable. But only my laptop gets the connection auto eth0; my desktop doesnt get that. Actually I changed my laptops mac ID same as my desktops. Does this some thing to do with this?